# rollback failed inside @ManagedBean class

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I use Bean-managed transaction inside `@ManagedBean` class to manually manage transactions,

```
@ManagedBean(name = "clients")
@ViewScoped
@URLMapping(id = "sousc", pattern = "/ccf_sicavs_customers", viewId = "/customers/PgSouscripteurs.jsf")
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class SouscripteursBean extends Referentiel implements Serializable {
 @Resource
    private UserTransaction ut;
    @EJB
 private CustomerDaoLocal ejbCust;
 public void createCustomer() {
try {
                    LOGGER.info("Debut de la transaction");
                    ut.begin();
                    LOGGER.info("begin() succeded");
                    currentMorale.setCodeSouscripteur("25");
                     saved=ejbCust.createCustomer(currentMorale);
                    ut.commit();
                     LOGGER.info("commit() succeded");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    saved=false;
                    try {
                        ut.rollback();
                        LOGGER.info("rollback() succeded");
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
                    }
                }
}
}
```

but if an `exception` is thrown thrown before the `commit()`, the `rollback()` failed
and throw this `java.lang.IllegalStateException`:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction is not active in the current thread.
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.validateTransactionManager(JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.java:447)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.rollbackDistributedTransaction(JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.java:208)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.rollback(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:899)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.UserTransactionImpl.rollback(UserTransactionImpl.java:234)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have that exception because the transaction is outside the EJB Container scope. 
JSF application is the EJB service client and the application is in WEB Container scope.

Normally you don't do any business logic in JSF managed bean. Managed beans are just controllers in the JSF ModelViewController architecture. The business logic should be done inside ejb's and inject them in JSF managed beans and only call the EJB methods with the functionality. Transactions, persistence, security etc should be done inside EJB.

Bottom line, the transaction should be done inside createCustomer() method from that EJB, not in managed bean.

Try that!